# How can I align 3 columns to the left inside div?

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with 3 columns, these are `span` tags:

```js
$('#id_size_0').attr('checked', true);

$(".quantity_50").html("S/.50");
$(".savings_50").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
$(".quantity_100").html("S/.70");
$(".savings_100").html("Ahorra 30%");
$(".quantity_200").html("S/.90");
$(".savings_200").html("Ahorra 55%");
$(".quantity_300").html("S/.108");
$(".savings_300").html("Ahorra 64%");
$(".quantity_500").html("S/.140");
$(".savings_500").html("Ahorra 78%");

$('input:radio[name="size"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '5cm x 5cm') {
    $(".quantity_50").html("S/.50");
    $(".savings_50").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    $(".quantity_100").html("S/.70");
    $(".savings_100").html("Ahorra 30%");
    $(".quantity_200").html("S/.90");
    $(".savings_200").html("Ahorra 55%");
    $(".quantity_300").html("S/.108");
    $(".savings_300").html("Ahorra 64%");
    $(".quantity_500").html("S/.140");
    $(".savings_500").html("Ahorra 78%");
  } else if ($(this).val() == '7cm x 7cm') {
    $(".quantity_50").html("S/.70");
    $(".savings_50").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    $(".quantity_100").html("S/.90");
    $(".savings_100").html("Ahorra 36%");
    $(".quantity_200").html("S/.130");
    $(".savings_200").html("Ahorra 54%");
    $(".quantity_300").html("S/.160");
    $(".savings_300").html("Ahorra 69%");
    $(".quantity_500").html("S/.240");
    $(".savings_500").html("Ahorra 66%");
  } else if ($(this).val() == '10cm x 10cm') {
    $(".quantity_50").html("S/.90");
    $(".savings_50").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    $(".quantity_100").html("S/.115");
    $(".savings_100").html("Ahorra 36%");
    $(".quantity_200").html("S/.180");
    $(".savings_200").html("Ahorra 50%");
    $(".quantity_300").html("S/.280");
    $(".savings_300").html("Ahorra 48%");
    $(".quantity_500").html("S/.450");
    $(".savings_500").html("Ahorra 50%");
  } else if ($(this).val() == '13cm x 13cm') {
    $(".quantity_50").html("S/.200");
    $(".savings_50").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    $(".quantity_100").html("S/.370");
    $(".savings_100").html("Ahorra 10%");
    $(".quantity_200").html("S/.430");
    $(".savings_200").html("Ahorra 46%");
    $(".quantity_300").html("S/.500");
    $(".savings_300").html("Ahorra 58%");
    $(".quantity_500").html("S/.900");
    $(".savings_500").html("Ahorra 55%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="semi-transparent padded rounded">
  <div class="bg-white rounded padded padded-40">
    <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="PjG1UJe5x6E2lb53BEbvWJ6tcKJcWfI15LWoB4bp57KMhoAGTDFyKuTtSkcILXpV">
      <div class="">
        <div id="size">
          <legend class="text-size16 bold-font"> Selecciona un tamaño</legend>
          <ul class="form-items">
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="size" value="5cm x 5cm" id="id_size_0" required> 5 cm x 5 cm</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="size" value="7cm x 7cm" id="id_size_1" required>  7 cm x 7 cm</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="size" value="10cm x 10cm" id="id_size_2" required> 10 cm x 10 cm</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="size" value="13cm x 13cm" id="id_size_3" required> 13 cm x 13 cm</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="quantity">
          <legend class="text-size16 bold-font"> Selecciona la cantidad</legend>
          <ul class="form-items">
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="quantity" value="50" id="id_quantity_0" required> 50</span>
              <span class="quantity_50"></span>
              <span class="savings_50"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="quantity" value="100" id="id_quantity_1" required> 100</span>
              <span class="quantity_100"></span>
              <span class="savings_100"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="quantity" value="200" id="id_quantity_2" required> 200</span>
              <span class="quantity_200"></span>
              <span class="savings_200"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="quantity" value="300" id="id_quantity_3" required> 300</span>
              <span class="quantity_300"></span>
              <span class="savings_300"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span><input type="radio" name="quantity" value="500" id="id_quantity_4" required> 500</span>
              <span class="quantity_500"></span>
              <span class="savings_500"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Continuar</button>

      <br><br>

      <p class="text-size10 text-center">Siguiente: subir imagen</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErLWgp))

The first column are radio buttons and their labels, the second is the cost, and the 3rd is the savings.

Besides using this code to align the radio buttons to the left, I'm not using something else with CSS, is this page:

```
form ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

form ul li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I was trying to use spaces (`&nbsp;`) to align items but it was just impossible to do it correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could try using a table?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it available (and runnable) on SO.

Comment: You can use CSS grid here.

Comment: The question is too broad. There are many ways to align content with HTML. What have you tried (aside from whitespace characters)? Are you using any front-end libraries that have layout mechanisms you can use?

Comment: Besides Bootstrap, none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a snip with css grid:

```
#quantity .form-items li {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

check the support against https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid
and polyfill if necessary the thing you're building / your users require.

Or if using grid is out of the question you can achieve similar with display:table

```
#quantity .form-items li {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
#quantity .form-items li span {
   display:table-cell;
   width: 33.33%;
}
```